# « Bon sang » pour dire « damn » ou « goddamn » pour montrer l’etonnement ?

Tags: traduction, argot, jurons

En anglais je dis très souvent « damn » ou « goddamn » à la fin d’une phrase (ou au début) quand je suis impressionné ou choqué. Par exemple mon ami m’a raconté sur son jardin et les sortes de fruits et légumes qu’il a. Il en a beaucoup donc je voulais dire « Wow, it’s like a real orchard, goddamn! »

Ou peut-être « Damn, that was so good! »

En français je dis bien « putain » mais quand je dis des trucs comme ça je préfère quelque chose d’un peu moins vulgaire (mais toujours au niveau de « damn/goddamn »).

Est-ce que « bon sang » suffirait ? Ou ça ne marche pas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bon sang" est plutôt soutenu. Tu vas le retrouver en littérature mais pas tant à l'oral. De façon familière, je dirais "putain". En langage courant : "Eh bah dis donc", "bordel".

> Eh bah dis donc, ça c'est du verger !
>
> Bordel, que c'était bon !

Comment: ah d’accord, je pige ! merci tellement, t’as grave aidé ! je savais pas que « dis donc » était si courant

Comment: @jacoballens N'oublie pas de marquer cette réponse comme réponse acceptée.

Comment: ah j’avoue, merci !

Comment: Pour moi "Bon sang" n'est pas soutenu. Dans certaines partie de la France, les gens disent "Vache !" ou " La vache !". Ne me demandez pas d'où ca vient ^^

Answer (score 1):

« *Bon sang* » n’est pas soutenu du tout (c’est au contraire très familier) mais est vieilli, ce qui est différent.

« *Bordel* » est tout aussi vulgaire que « *Putain* » (l’un étant le lieu de travail de l’autre).

Afin d’utiliser un language familier mais non vulgaire, tout en évitant le recours au vocabulaire du XVIIe siècle, il existe quelques solutions :

- « *Dis donc* » comme évoqué par @Strebler peut faire l’affaire mais risque d’être utilisé de manière un peu artificielle par un non-natif ;
- « *Mince* » peut paraître enfantin mais je le vois utilisé autour de moi (région parisienne et ouest de la France, en milieu éduqué) ;
- L’utilisation de phrases exclamatives (par exemple, « *Incroyable !* » ou « *C’est génial !* », voire « *Quelle horreur !* » pour une surprise négative) me paraît la solution la plus adaptée à ce type de discussion familière pour exprimer son étonnement ou sa surprise sans utiliser « *Putain* » ou « *Bordel* » (qui me valaient des claques si prononcés dans le cercle famillial et que je ne saurais toujours pas utiliser en compagnie de mon N+2 en entreprise).